# Warning message when build or deploy angular project with firebase

Tags: angular, deployment, build, warnings

I got the message below: When I deploy or build an angular project, how do I fix it?

mohammedalfadhel@Mohammeds-Mac-mini app % ng build --configuration production
⠋ Building...
▲ [WARNING] Module '@grpc/grpc-js' used by 'node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.mjs' is not ESM

CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more information see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

▲ [WARNING] Module '@grpc/proto-loader' used by 'node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.mjs' is not ESM

CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more information see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

▲ [WARNING] Module 'undici' used by 'node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index.js' is not ESM

CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more information see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

▲ [WARNING] Module 'undici' used by 'node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js' is not ESM

CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more information see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

⠸ Building...